# Apache server in raspberry PI not visible from outside( public IP)

Tags: networking, arch-linux, ip

I have made a fresh install of Arch Linux ARM into a Raspberry PI and I mounted there a LAMP, all fresh.

I have another Arch(x86) in my laptop with Apache also there, and as far as I know, two web servers cannot run in the same network segment so, the problem is as follows.

In my laptop, having Apache running, if I enter via the public ip of my network everything turns ok and I can see my website but, (obviously turning this server down) if I enter from the public IP with the Apache running in the raspberry pi( yes, only that Apache running) i cannot see my website in there. 
Also, if I access via local network it is a normal success, I can see my website.
So, I can enter my raspberry website only via local but in my other web server i can enter it via local and public.

I have the same conf files in both of them so what is the difference?
I was planning in making the rpi as a development server.
Thanks in advance

Comment: btw, both are listening at port 80

Comment: we do not consider the RPi to be a server platform within the meaning of SF. The enthusiast nature of the device makes questions regarding it a better fit for [su] or [unix.se] or possibly so long as the question is not UNIX/Linux related [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: mmm yeah, it could be true, if it's considered that way I'll move this post to the rpi forum

Comment: "two web servers cannot run in the same network segment so, the problem is as follows" — this statement is false. However if, as I think you have suggested, you have a NAT between you and the internet, and you have a private network, then the nat will only be able to port forward a port to one server. If the nat is clever it could forward different domain names to different servers. You have to tell the nat which server to forward to.

Comment: I can not make sense of paragraph 3, the words do not seem to be in order. Please read it to your self, and edit to make it clear.

Comment: @Iain, I don't think the raspberry pi bit is relevant. It is an Arch Gnu+Linux question. I suspect also that the problem is with the NAT.

Comment: @Kronos, if both servers are on the same ip address in your network, then yes, they will conflict. If they both have the same ip address make sure one is on and the other is off when testing. If they are on different ip addresses then you need to point the forwarding of public port 80 in your router to the ip address of the other local machine.

Comment: @captcha Ohh I get it, yeah as you say, just one is running at once while the other is off but, doesn't the forwarding of the port is made automatically with the web server's listening? Because I don't have an specialized router so I think I cannot re-route from there, let me check.

Comment: @richard yes, there's a nat but only one web server is running at once; even so, I need to tell which want to forward to? Btw, paragraph 3 seems fine to me, just a missing "n" in the firs word

Comment: @Kronos, most off-the-shelf routers for home use will have features with a built-in firewall, NAT, and port-forwarding. In order to forward public (WAN, Outside) port 80 to a local network machine you will need to log in to the router and configure TO WHICH LOCAL IP the port 80 should be forwarded to. If your ISP is blocking incoming port 80 perhaps you could try forwarding public port 8080 to local port 80.

Comment: @richard For your elucidation, we discussed this on Server Fault and our decision was, that, in general RPi related questions would be from enthusiasts which puts the platform outside the scope of Server Fault. http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5586/are-raspberrypis-ever-on-topic-for-serverfault

Comment: Don't fight people, I already checked my router and you were right @captcha , my router was routing port 80 by default, I created a rule for it and now rpi works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My router was routing port 80 by default, I created a rule for it and now rpi works fine. Thanks